# Fractional distillation of crude oil and resulting fuel ratios

Tags: distillation, petrochemistry

I understand from the diagram below that different fuels condense at different temperatures. But I don't know anything about crude oil (and very little about chemistry in general).
Could I simply refine 100% of crude oil to gasoline by heating it up to 150 °C (value taken from diagram).

Put another way, are the ratios of end products from refining crude oil fixed?

[image: Crude Oil Distillation]

Comment: Sorry, are you asking if: if you had a gallon of crude and let it sit and simmer at 150 degrees, would you wind up with a gallon of gasoline eventually? Because I'm not clear on what you're asking, but that is emphatically not how fractional distillation works.

Comment: Thank you, your comment was helpful. I was wondering whether I can only produce gasoline from crude oil. No Diesel, no kerosene, nothing else. Or is there a fixed relationship, e.g., 1 gallon of crude results in 0.x gallons of gasoline, 0.x gallons of Diesel, and so on.

Comment: You never get 100% pure anything from fractional distillation.

Answer (score 2):

Crude oil is a complicated mixture consisting of a variety of different hydrocarbons and the particular composition is very variable depending on where it is found.

Distillation is merely a means of separating those components so it can do nothing to create *more* of one of them. And gasoline is, essentially, just a mixture of those components with similar properties and boiling points. There is little you can do *by distillation* to create more gasoline.

However refiners do have access to chemical means to alter the composition. Catalytic cracking, for example, converts constituents into different chemicals and this can allow a refinery to create more gasoline or diesel by breaking down the higher-boiling components into smaller parts. But this is *much* more complicated than distillation.

Answer (score 1):

I see where you are coming from but I don't think you can simply get gasoline by heating crude oil to 150°C. There are few more important steps that should be taken before putting crude oil into the furnace.
Have a look. (Picture taken from Wikipedia)

[image: Fractional Distillation]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was aiming at a different aspect, though. I was wondering whether distillation of crude oil always yields the same ratios of fuel or if that ratio can be influenced. E.g., you'll always end up with 20% gasoline, 20% Diesel, and so on. (I know very little about chemistry and just randomly picked numbers here.)